# How to join t4 element using comma separator in js file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, t4

Hi; i would like to generate Js file to access using best overload method from js files. i can create a js file as aproprite format by T4. But my properties in js file is  separated each other by commas. Look please : http://jsaction.codeplex.com/

```
JsActions.Categories = {
```

CategoriesByCategoryID: function (CategoryID) {///
},

CategoriesByCategoryName: function (CategoryName) {///
},

CategoriesByDescription: function (Description) {///
},

CategoriesByPicture: function (Picture) {///
} ,

}

Look above; Last comma must not be here. How to modify my t4 template. i think "string.Join Method " but i can not.

```
     <#@ template language="C#" Debug="true" #>

<#@ output extension=".js" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml"#>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" #>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" #>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>


JsActions.<#=tab.Name.ToString()#> ={
<#           foreach (Column col in tab.Columns)
            {#>
string[] myValues = new string[] { ... };
string csvString = string.Join(",", HOW TO JOIN BELOW ROW ?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????);

<#= tab.Name.ToString()#>By<#=col.Name#>: function (<#=col.Name#>) {///</param>
},

<#           }#>

}

<#  }}#>
```

LOOK Please : <#= tab.Name.ToString()#>By<#=col.Name#>: function (<#=col.Name#>) {///
},

i should remove last property's comma...How to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibility 1 (without string.Join):
Iterate over the collection by an index and only render the comma if it is not the last entry

```
    for(int i=0;i<tab.Columns.Count;i++)
    {
        <#= tab.Name.ToString() #>By<#=tab.Columns[i].Name#>: function (<#=tab.Columns[i].Name#>) 
        { ///<param> } <#= (i == tab.Columns.Count - 1) ? string.Empty : ", " #>
    }
```

Possibility 2 (with string.Join):
Use a helper method that returns an IEnumerable of string to be joined by string.Join method.

```
IEnumerable<string> GetLines(...)
{
    var list = new List<string>();
    foreach(var col in tab.Columns)
    {
        list.Add(tab.Name.ToString() + "By" + col.Name + ": function(" + col.Name 
                 + ") { /// <param> }");
    }
    return list;
}
```

And then use

```
JsActions.<#=tab.Name.ToString()#> = { 
    <#= string.Join(", ", GetLines(tab)) #> }...
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: You could also make the GetLines method an iterator and flip out to markup syntax within that method.  Then it will add a line every time it is called.  Finally, use linq to Aggregate the enum and in the aggregator function write out the comma.

Answer (score 2):

A more elegant solution may be to create a Join method which takes a separator and an action which you can use like this:

```
<# myArray.Join(",", (arrayItem, separator) => { #>
  My item: <#= arrayItem #><#= separator#>
<# }); #>
```

You put `<#=separator#>` where you want the separator to go.  It gets replaced by the separator you pass in, except for the last item which gets an empty string.

You will need to declare the following extension method somewhere:

```
public static void Join<T>(this IEnumerable<T> e, string separator, Action<T, string> action)
{
    using (var t = e.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!t.MoveNext())
            return;
        for (;;)
        {
            T current = t.Current;
            bool last = !t.MoveNext();
            action(current, last ? "" : separator);
            if (last)
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great helper method!  Just a note — it would be better to place `e.GetEnumerator` inside `using` since it is required to dispose enumerators.

Comment: I've changed your method so it writes separator itself.  I wrapped the method into class feature block `<#+...#>` and added a call to `this.Write`: `if (!last) this.Write(separator);`.  Now it is like `string.Join` method and I don't need to remember about separator in the `action` delegate.